# Таблица с аудиоплеерами в jupiter

Tags: python, dataframe, аудио

Как я могла бы сделать такую таблицу, если у меня есть датафрейм, в котором содержатся названия аудиозаписей?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: данный вопрос в виде картинки следует закрыть, потому что он бесполезен для базы знаний (тот, у кого возникнет подобный вопрос, не сможет найти данный вопрос и ответы к нему)